# How am I switching between an uncontrolled/controlled input? React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has an `input`:

```
state = {
    org: {
        orgName: ''
    }
};

updateInput = field => event => {
    this.setState({
        org: {
            [field]: event.target.value
        }
    })
}

render() {
    let { org } = this.state
    return (
        <input
            value={org.orgName}
            onChange={this.updateInput('orgName')}
        />
    )
}
```

I initialize the `input` value to `''`, but as soon as I type anything into the `input`, I get this error:

```
A component is changing a controlled input of type undefined to be uncontrolled
```

I thought if I initialized the `input`, then it would always be controlled, but apparently this is wrong.  What is the proper way for this `input` to always be controlled?

Comment: What happens when you change `updateInput` to `updateInput = event => ...` and replace `[field]` with `orgName` while passing just `this.updateInput` to the input

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `this.state = {
      org: {
        orgName: ''
      }
    }`.Check this one https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. https://codesandbox.io/s/1z7x5oqv23

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://codesandbox.io/s/w7zm7vo76l

Comment: That error is likely coming from somewhere else, there's nothing wrong with how that input is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format:

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        org: {
            orgName: ''
        }
    };
}


updateInput = (field, event) => {
    this.setState({
        org: {
            [field]: event.target.value
        }
    })
}

render() {
    let { org } = this.state
    return (
        <input
            value={org.orgName}
            onChange={(event) => {this.updateInput('orgName', event)}}
        />
    )
}
```

If you use it like this then you get:

1. place state inside a constructor so you can change it with `this.setState`.
2. `onChange` is being fired only when an event is happening and not automatically fired.
3. You need to pass the event down through the handler chain so the handler as access to it.
4. not sure what you meant by `updateInput = field => event => {}` there is no event in the chain at that point so you cannot access it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: `updateInput = field => event => {}` is just a function that returns a new function. That new function takes the `event` as its argument. There's nothing wrong with doing that except that it creates a new function object every time the component renders (which is basically what you're doing as well). Also, state doesn't need to be declared in a constructor, OP is likely using [a class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which is a stage 3 proposal for the spec.

Comment: Thanks for leaving a teaching comment instead of down voting!!! Regarding the first part of your comment, when you write it that way do you have an access to the fired event? also when writing in like so `onChange={this.updateInput('orgName')}` is the event being fired as expected or directly on the initial render?

Comment: No problem. I've tried to explain it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEmgoQ?editors=0011). There's probably better explanations around if you google for *higher order functions*. The way OP used it means they don't have to declare several `onChange` handlers if they have more inputs. They can simply reuse the generic one.

Comment: The event is going to be fired as expected in this case, since `updateInput` just returns a function and the event gets passed to that function when it is triggered. It's the reference to the inner function that gets passed to `onChange`.

Comment: So when I go this route, it works fine, but as @ivami said, there should be nothing wrong with returning a function from a function.  When I went to the pen from [Hardik Modha](https://codesandbox.io/s/1z7x5oqv23), it did work fine.  I don't know what is wrong with my environment.